# como obtener repetidos arreglos

Tags: python

me piden dado dos arreglos de números enteros de igual elementos cada
uno. ordenarlos de mayor a menor y obtener un nuevo arreglo que contenga
únicamente los elementos repetidos. yo ya lo ordene pero no se como obtener los elementos repetidos en un nuevo arreglo.

```
def orden(acumulado):
for k in range(6):
    for x in range(6-k):
        if acumulado[x]<acumulado[x+1]:
            aux=acumulado[x]
            acumulado[x]=acumulado[x+1]
            acumulado[x+1]=aux
return acumulado 


n=7
m=7
lista = [0]  * n
lista1 = [0]  * m


for i in range(n):
    lista[i] = random.randint(1, 10) 
for i in range(m):
    lista1[i] = random.randint(1, 10)  

print(orden(lista))
print()
print(orden(lista1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te están exigiendo que desarrolles los algoritmos como tal, pero considerando que estás aprendiendo Python, compartiré la manera *Pythonic* de hacer lo que quieres:

```
list_1 = [3, 5, 1]
list_2 = [9, 4, 3]

list_1.sort()
list_2.sort()

list_3 = list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))

print(list_1, list_2, list_3, sep=', ')
# El output será: [1, 3, 5], [3, 4, 9], [3]
```

**A saber del código anterior:**

1. En primer lugar Python no tiene arreglos (al menos no de forma nativa) sino listas, los cuales son objetos de la clase `list`. Esta clase contiene un [método de ordenamiento muy efectivo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (`sort()`) con el cual podrás ordenar tus listas.
2. No me queda claro si se buscan elementos repetidos dentro de cada arreglo, o elementos repetidos entre ambos arreglos, pero parece ser la segunda opción. Para esto vienen siendo muy útiles los [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (o conjuntos). Los objetos de tipo `set` te permiten obtener elementos únicos a partir de un conjunto de elementos. Acá lo que hacemos es buscar la [intersección](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) de dos conjuntos creados a partir de tus listas (`list_1` y `list_2`), y convertir el resultado de esta intersección de conjuntos, en una nueva lista (`list_3`).

Answer (score 1):

Otra paradigma a la respuesta de revliscano, podría ser añadir las siguientes líneas al final de tu código:

```py
... 
print(orden(lista1))

elemetos_repetidos = list()
for elemento in lista:
    if elemento in lista1:
        if elemento not in elemetos_repetidos:
            elemetos_repetidos.append(elemento)

print(elemetos_repetidos)
```

Para añadir un elemento repetido a la lista `elemetos_repetidos`, se deben cumplir dos condiciones:

1. Que el elemento si este dentro de la otra lista (`lista1`)
2. Que el elemento no este dentro de la lista `elemetos_repetidos`. resulta que existe la posibilidad que el mismo numero este repetido varias veces en las dos lista. Así evitas que la lista `elemetos_repetidos` al final contenga, por ejemplo de dos o más 8...